# Angular Universal with initialNavigation enabled and CanActivateChild returning false not responding

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-universal, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have an Angular application with SSR where all routes are protected and the Router `initialNavigation` property is set to `enabled`. I'm using the [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc) package with Code Flow + PKCE. All routes are lazy loaded and I have a `CanActivateChild` guard checking if the user is authenticated.

When in the browser, the `CanActivateChild` checks if it's authenticated and if it's not, it redirects to an Azure AD B2C to perform the authentication. This is working fine when running without SSR.

When in the server, the `CanActivateChild` if it's not authenticated, it just cancels the navigation by returning `false` but there is no redirection. The idea is to return with no activated route, just the root component rendered/bootstrapped, since it's not authenticated and let the browser handle the authentication. I leave that to the browser since the [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc) is for the browser platform, some functionalities in the `OAuthService` don't work on the server since it depends on some browser APIs, I do have an `OAuthStorage` implementations for each platform so I can get the token on each platform. With this setup, the Express.js server does not to respond, which I assume is because the bootstrapping of the application is waiting for the navigation to complete since `initialNavigation` is `enabled`. I was expecting this to work fine, since a cancellation in a sense, is a completion of the navigation as well.

I can think on a couple of ways to workaround this, like disabling `initialNavigation` which is not good since this will cause the page to flicker (so it's a no), or redirecting to an empty component just to complete the navigation, or manually redirect in the server to the Azure AD B2C authorize endpoint, etc.

Has anyone came across this and has a better solution? Am I missing something or am I configuring something wrong?

Edit, adding some snippets:

AuthGuard:

```js
canActivateChild(
    _: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      tap((isAuthenticated) => isAuthenticated || this.authService.login(state.url)),
    );
  }
```

The `authService.isAuthenticated$` is a an `Observable` from a `BehaviorSubject` which in the server just sends if the token is in the cookies. I verified and in the server is successfully returning `false` when there is no token stored and `true` otherwise. When it's true everything works fine since the navigation completes.

The `authService.login` method in the browser calls the `OAuthService.initCodeFlow` method. In the server it's an empty method.

Comment: can you share the code of the guard here?

Comment: @Ayyash I edited the question with more details.

Comment: did you try wrapping the if statement with the platform check? do the if statement only on browser and return false on server?

Comment: @Ayyash what if statement? if you refer to what's inside the `tap` operator, that operator doesn't affect the stream, so it does effectively return `false` when there is no token in the request cookies. As I said above, when the token is there it does run fine.

Comment: If the platform is browser return isAuthenticated$ else return of(null), may be?

Comment: @Ayyash that won't do, if I do that then I won't ever process the route on the server if the user is authenticated, which like I said, it's a scenario that's working fine. The `AuthGuard` is definitely not the problem here, it's correctly returning `true` or `false` depending on the authentication status. I believe the issue is Angular expects a route to be resolved in the initial navigation, otherwise it just doesn't bootstrap the root component. According to the docs, setting `initialNavigation` to `enabled` do block the bootstrapping until navigation is completed.